# How to use pygame and pyglet at the same time

Tags: python, pygame, pyglet

I'm using the pygame and pyglet libraries I want to create a window but it happens that the pygame window is created first and when you close it the pyglet window is created, I want them to be created at the same time.

Here is the code

```
import pyglet 
from pyglet.window import key
import pygame

background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (300, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
screen.fill(background_colour)
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=134,height=132)#se crea la ventana
mos = 17
@window.event #funcion on_key_press se ejecuta mientra la funcion windows se ejecuta
def on_key_press(key_pressed, mod):
    if key_pressed == key.RIGHT:
        label.x+=5  
    if key_pressed == key.LEFT:
        label.x-=5        
    if key_pressed == key.UP:
        global mos
        mos+=1
        label.text=(str(mos))
label = pyglet.text.Label(str(mos),
                          font_name='Times New Roman',
                          font_size=mos,
                          x=window.width//2, y=window.height//2,
                          anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
@window.event#funcion on_key_press se ejecuta mientra la funcion windows se ejecuta
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Why do you want to use pygame and pyglet at the same time?

Comment: Because I like both   Pyglet has things that pygame do not have and vice versa

Comment: You can not use pygame and pyglet at the same time. From the experience I have I have seen that you can do almost all things in both cases, except that in pyglet you can work with 3D

Comment: I've been using both for a couple of years now, and I gotta agree with eyllanesc here on this one. What does Pygame have that pyglet doesn't? If you can mention a few maybe we can point you at something that solves it?

Answer (score 0):

*Pygame* and *Pyglet* are both windowing frameworks. You can use either one or the other, but not both together. Event and window handling get in conflict with each other and cause undefined behavior.